# как узнать ширину консоли на С

Tags: c

нужна функция, которая будет выводить строку из '*' по длине равной ширине консоли. саму функцию понимаю как написать, нужно понять как-то какая конкретная ширина консоли

Comment: Для \*nix-ов читайте [man ioctl_tty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html) (конкретно про TIOCGWINSZ)